# Find the area of a polygon whose number of sides we don't know

Tags: javascript, arrays, polygon, area

I want to find the area of the polygon on JavaScript. We don't know the number of sides, and we find the length of the sides by the coordinates of the points.

Here's my code. which works incorrectly. I think I have an error in arrays, but I can't figure out where exactly. The distance between points is found by the formula sqrt ((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 ).

```js
function Klass() {

  KolGran = prompt("Введите количество граней");
  KolGran = parseInt(KolGran);
  Per = 0;

  var myMatrix = matrixArray(1,KolGran);

  for(var i=0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    for(var j=0; j < KolGran; j++)
    {
      Chislo = prompt("Введите координаты");
      Chislo = parseInt(Chislo);
      myMatrix[i][j] = Chislo;
    }
  }

  alert (myMatrix);

  var ST = 0;

  for(var i=0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    for(var j=0; j <= KolGran; j++)
    {
      ST = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( (Chislo[i+1][j]-Chislo[i][j]) ,2) + Math.pow( (Chislo[i+1][j+1]-Chislo[i][j+1]) , 2 ) );
      Per = Per + ST;
    }
  }

  Alert(ST)

}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="Klass()">2.2</a>
<br/>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<noscript>
  <p> JS ON !</p>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Are you calculate perimeter of polygon or area ?

Comment: Could you perhaps translate your variables into English, that way your code would be easier to parse for the larger audience.

Comment: If you're sure your polygon isn't self-intersecting you can use the method described here [Algorithm to find the area of a polygon](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea2.html)